# Get object value with Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm building a nice app with CodeIgniter and Ajax JQuery which returns finally a nice JSON like object looking like the following out of the success function via `console.log ()`:

```
        var data2 = {"field":fieldname,
                "pagetitle":userdata};
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata_ajax",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data2,
                success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

The result of the success function:

[image]

Since quite a while I'm trying to get just one value out of that object. I tried

- `console.log (data.id)`
- `console.log (data[id])`
- etc

but nothing worked. I'm sure its just a stupid thing. Any help?

Comment: It looks like `data` is an array containing one object...

Comment: @FelixKling is right. You'll need to use `console.log(data[0].id)` in that case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**data** is an array in this case so use an index to get the first object:

```
data[0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[0].id
```

min chars min chars

Answer (score 1):

The data object seems to be an array to you have to use something like `console.log(data[0].id)`.